# How to get the difference of 2 lists in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I'm new to python Pandas. I faced a problem to find the difference for 2 lists within a Pandas DataFrame.

Example Input with `;` separator:

```
ColA; ColB  
A,B,C,D; B,C,D  
A,C,E,F; A,C,F
```

Expected Output:

```
ColA; ColB; ColC  
A,B,C,D; B,C,D; A  
A,C,E,F; A,C,F; E
```

What I want to do is similar to:

```
df['ColC'] = np.setdiff1d(df['ColA'].str.split(','), df['ColB'].str.split(','))
```

But it returns an error:

> raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of index',data,index,len(data),len(index))

Kindly advise

Comment: hi, you want [A,B,C,D] - [B,C,D] = [A]?  if it is the case then "result = list((Counter(L1) - Counter(L2)).elements())" should do the job

Comment: how do you read your file? can you show me that part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a lambda function on the DataFrame to find the difference like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# creating DataFrame (can also be loaded from a file)
df = pd.DataFrame([[['A','B','C','D'], ['B','C']]], columns=['ColA','ColB'])

# apply a lambda function to get the difference
df['ColC'] = df[['ColA','ColB']].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x[0] if i not in x[1]], axis=1)
```

**Please notice!** this will find the asymmetric difference ColA - ColB

Result:

[image: difference of two lists pandas]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly and saved my day!
As beginner I guess i need to learn hard  how to use apply or transform.

Answer (score 0):

A lot faster way to do this would be a simple set subtract:

```
import pandas as pd

#Creating a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([[['A','B','C','D'], ['B','C']]], columns=['ColA','ColB'])

#Finding the difference
df['ColC']= df['ColA'].map(set)-df['ColB'].map(set)
```

As the dataframe grows in row numbers, it will be computationally pretty expensive to do any row by row operation.